# meaning of "divvy up"

Tags: meaning, morphology

[A tutorial coins a word "divvy"](https://youtu.be/RvCbTYJqepU?t=153)

[image]

["div" is an HTML tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.ASP), could simply be considered a section in a document.

I guess the morpheme used in the coining word might have some common meanings, like [Pythoneer and Pythonista](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-exact-difference-between-a-Pythoneer-and-a-Pythonista). For this particular example, what does "vy" mean?

Comment: In the UK, 'divvy up' is slang for 'divide up'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you. Does "divide up" mean something like "break down"? Suppose I am doing a math question, m + (n - q), breaking it down gets "m" and "(n - q)".

Comment: If I have a cake and I cut it into pieces, I am dividing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` tag is short for division.

To "divvy up" means to "divide up", with the earliest uses of "divvy" as a noun and an abbreviation of dividend.

The words are cognates of each other and come from Latin *dividere* (which is ultimately formed as *dis videre* = "apart separate"

"vy" has no independent meaning.  Divvy is just a spelling of "divi".  The "y" can be seen as a diminutive and the "v" is duplication which is common before "y".  Compare "pup" → "puppy" which shows the same duplication of the noun and the diminutive "y".